# Printing API in Android

Tags: android, printing

I've downloaded a utility called PrintShare which allows one to print things like web pages, contact lists, calendars, etc to a printer connected through wireless or a computer participating on the PrintShare network.

I would like to have my Android app create a text file, then send that text file to a printer that is shared with PrintShare.

Is there an API for printing on Android?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All which need a printing API in Android should vote for it.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1148

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13275

Currently there are some bad working third party apps. Nothing is a professional solution.

Comment: Now there is an API in 4.4! :))
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Printing

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an API for printing on Android?

<strike>Not natively. There might be some from third parties, but nothing built into the OS.</strike>

Android 4.4 and higher has [a printing API](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html) that you can use.

Comment: I don't know if you're looking to print a full sized document or a receipt. One option for a receipt printing API is here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

Answer (score 3):

From Android 4.4 provided API Printing

http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iub67ic87KI

Answer (score 2):

Bixolon is a company that sells printers of all types. In fact, it sells printers that can connect with Android applications by an API (SDK).

Here some real example:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=op_j80zVL78

And here more information about it (Bixolon SPP-R200)
[Android: Connecting and Printing to Bixolon SPP-R200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702888/android-connecting-and-printing-to-bixolon-spp-r200)

If anyone knows another company or printers, please share!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out [www.lob.com](http://www.lob.com), they have a nice printing and mailing API that is easy to integrate with Android!

Answer (score 0):

**Android now includes a complete framework that allows users to print any document using a printer connected over Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, or other services. The system handles the transaction between an app that wants to print a document and the services that deliver print jobs to a printer. The android.print framework provides all the APIs necessary to specify a print document and deliver it to the system for printing. Which APIs you actually need for a given print job depends on your content.**

Kindly refer to the following url:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/package-summary.html