# Android How to use printing application within my app to print text file without Internet

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I have to develop android application for creating and printing invoices.
Can you propose me a solution how to print text files from this my application using bluetooth printer through some application but without need to connect to internet ? I know that there is PrinterSahre, EpsonPrint , EasyPrint - but they usually allow only to print office documents and have own GUI and need to connect to Internet. 
I would rather need to use some API to silently print file without need from user to again choose file on a memory card and print . So is there a solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160661/printing-api-in-android

Comment: http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/140-api-for-printing-from-android-applications

Comment: thanks.. these solutions are not exactly what i need but very helpfull