# Scan wifi printers inside an available network

Tags: java, android, wifi, network-printers

How can I get the available printers inside the range of my wifi? For example, with wifimanager I can identify the available networks around but how can I get about the printers inside each network?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160661/printing-api-in-android

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid the answer is really short: Not.

Comment: PrintHand application can list available wifi printers inside network. I assume somehow there is a way to do that.

Comment: Yes, but then you are probably connected to the network. Your question is looking for all printers in your area that have their wifi enabled, without your device being connected to the network of the printers.